# Stream movies on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, cloud, video-streaming

I have a Chrome OS netbook that I would like to watch my videos on. Is there some way to stream videos from the cloud (i.e: not my computer) to Chrome? I'm thinking using Amazon S3 but that might not work. Any solution that wouldn't require reencoding my library of `mkv` files would be the best.

Any solution that would allow me to watch on my iPad would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

The ipad solution is [airvideo](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/), they have a linux server (which can do live reencoding). As it streams in mp4 / H264 can you use mplayer for playback in chrome?

Comment: You mean to hose my own server with all the files on there? I checked out their linux server thread, seems too hard and not at all worth it. I already have airvideo for streaming from the computer, need something cloud based now.

Comment: Not hard at all, I run the airvideo server on my home linux box. It could be run "in the cloud". Good luck in finding an alternative.